# Problems with su: Authentication Failure

Tags: command-line, authentication, c, su

I am currently using Ubuntu and am 100% new to Unix. I have installed Ubuntu to program in C and will be using the "Learn C the Hard Way" online textbook (http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex0.html). I attempted the section in the textbook meant for setting up your computer and the second command is causing me some problems.

The first command in the link above executes without issue but when I try and run the second command:

```
$ su -c yum groupinstall development-tools
```

it prompts me for my password and when I enter it, it says

> su: Authentication Failure

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Would you take some time to review the answers then accept the one you like. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Look again at the web page. You are trying, wrongly, to run a command for an RPM based Linux like Fedora. Instead, run the command that says:

For Debian based systems, like Ubuntu you should just have to install a few things using these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is Debian based, use the first command and leave the second which is for Redhat based like Fedora.

> **Linux**
>
> On most Linux systems you just have to install a few packages. **For
>   Debian based systems, like Ubuntu** you should just have to install a
>   few things using these commands:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
> ```
>
> The above is an example of a command line prompt, so to get to where
>   you can run that, find your "Terminal" program and run it first. Then
>   you'll get a shell prompt similar to the $ above and can type that
>   command into it. Do not type the `$`, just the stuff after it.
>
> Here's how you would install the same setup **on an RPM based Linux like
>   Fedora:**
>
> ```
> $ su -c "yum groupinstall development-tools"
> ```

Once you've run that, you should be able to do the first Exercise in this book and it'll work. If not then let me know.

Anyway, that error message from `su` because you need to enter the *root password*. It is not the same as `sudo` which you use *your own user password*.

Comment: Man that guy is right, I have no reading comprehension. Thank you.

Comment: the terminal program is run by entering: <ctr;l><alt><T>